# How can i optimize MariaDB's my.cnf file? (with mysqltuner result)

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf, mysqltuner

I am using MariaDB & Apache (LAMP) and my VPS Ram is 512MB.

Now the problem is sometimes when i use `top`, the MariaDB process is using 506MB of RAM so i want to optimize my MariaDB.

Here is my `./mysqltuner.pl`'s result:

```
[!!] Currently running unsupported MySQL version 10.0.11-MariaDB-log
[OK] Operating on 32-bit architecture with less than 2GB RAM

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MyISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 33M (Tables: 94)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 6M (Tables: 111)
[--] Data in CSV tables: 0B (Tables: 2)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 4

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 8m 39s (3K q [7.657 qps], 39 conn, TX: 32M, RX: 513K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Total buffers: 94.0M global + 26.3M per thread (50 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.4G (282% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/3K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 4% (2/50)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 4.0M/3.9M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.0% (29K cached / 281 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 40.9% (2K cached / 6K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 481 sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 35% (75 on disk / 213 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 94% (2 created / 39 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 493% (79 open / 16 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (52/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1K immediate / 1K locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 64.0M/6.3M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 8M)
```

and here is my my.cnf's content:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

basedir = /usr/local/mariadb
datadir = /data/mariadb
pid-file = /data/mariadb/mysql.pid
user = mysql
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
server-id = 1

skip-name-resolve
#skip-networking
back_log = 300

max_connections = 20
max_connect_errors = 6000
open_files_limit = 65535
table_open_cache = 128 
max_allowed_packet = 4M
binlog_cache_size = 1M
max_heap_table_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 16M

read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M
key_buffer_size = 4M

thread_cache_size = 8

query_cache_size = 8M
query_cache_limit = 2M

ft_min_word_len = 4

log_bin = mysql-bin
binlog_format = mixed
expire_logs_days = 30

log_error = /data/mariadb/mysql-error.log
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log_file = /data/mariadb/mysql-slow.log

performance_schema = 0

#lower_case_table_names = 1

skip-external-locking

default_storage_engine = InnoDB
#default-storage-engine = MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_open_files = 500
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64M
innodb_write_io_threads = 4
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_purge_threads = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 32M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120

bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
myisam_repair_threads = 1

interactive_timeout = 28800
wait_timeout = 30

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer = 4M
write_buffer = 4M
```

I have no idea what i can do. Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the last version available on github.
Memory advice seems to be wrong andhave been corrected since.

Temporary table can be configurated with tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size variable.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/19/tmp_table_size-and-max_heap_table_size/